# Integer input of a Task in Verilog

Tags: verilog

When using integer as the input of a task, should I use the term "input" as well? Please see the task written below. At Line 2, should it be with or with the term input? I will call this task as below:

any_bit_command(5,15)

```
    task any_bit_command;
    input integer the_length_of_the_command;
    input [3:0] command_to_be_written;
    integer i;
    begin
    CNV = 1'b1;
    #10000;
    for (i = the_length_of_the_command; i > -1; i = i - 1) begin
    SCK = 1'b0;
    SDI = command_to_be_written[i];
    #60000;
    SCK = 1'b1;
    #60000;
    end
    #30000;
    CNV = 1'b0;
    #200000; 
    end
```

Comment: If you omit the `input` it is not an input but a local variable. I have no idea if you are allowed to define local variable before the I/O ports. I have never tried it so I would have to read the standard or try it out. (The latter is faster...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need the `input` keyword using this very old Verilog syntax to declare the task arguments.  Verilog-2001 (18 years ago, and there have been 4 revisions since then) added ANSI-C style argument definitions, and the default direction is `input`. So you can now write

```
task any_bit_command (
     integer the_length_of_the_command,
     reg [3:0] command_to_be_written
);
```